# Cabal install error: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix

Tags: mingw, ghc, cabal

I'm trying to install `network` and `old-time` with cabal-install. When I try to install either it fails with:

```
setup.exe: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a
Unix compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
```

I do have MinGW, in fact it's the MinGW distributed along with GHC.
I've also added the bin folder to my PATH.

How can I fix this? what tool is the one actually running the configure files? maybe I need to get it?

GHC 7.10.1 x64
cabal-install version 1.22.0.0
using version 1.22.0.0 of the Cabal library.
And I'm actually on a Windows 10 pro insider preview build 10130. I did the above a bunch of time on 7 and 8.1 and it never happened. I can't imagine why but maybe it plays a role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your quoted block:

> ... This requires a Unix compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS
>   ...

explicitly says `MinGW+MSYS`; MinGW alone is not enough. It is the MSYS tool chain which provides the unix compatible shell and most common supporting utilities, which allow this combination to process your configure script.

Comment: I've rolled back an edit which recommends adding `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` to your PATH. This is extremely ___bad___ advice, and you should not do so. What you should do is start MSYS, using the msys.bat script which it provides; this ensures that the PATH is correctly defined while MSYS is running, but removes the temptation to use MSYS tools improperly, from a `cmd.exe` shell.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Step 2 in
https://www.haskell.org/platform/
also check your cabal config file.
If there are multiple entries (lines) for extra-prog-path, the separator should be ";" and not "," on Windows.

Comment: Thanks this saved me!

Comment: This did not work for me. But replacing both lines with just 'extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\msys\usr\bin' did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Facing the exact same issue, after having installed Haskell Platform, I realised that I did not make Step 2 explained in this install procedure here

https://www.haskell.org/platform/

Doing so solved my issue